# How to add our own options in Visual Studio for target platform?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How to add our own options in Visual Studio for target platform like the below image?[image]

Comment: No, there is no option to add custom or additional target platform.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Configuration Manager..."

[image]

In the project configuration select

[image]

Name the new configuration:

[image]

And finally choose it for the desired project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted is, I want to give options for the users with multiple platforms (for which you have explained above) and a start button. Then I will launch html page on clicking the start button. How can i find out which platform is selected when start is clicked.